# Ajax button initiates every button, not just the one selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django, django-views

I would like to create an ajax button that once clicked, the item becomes "purchased" by the user. Once the item becomes purchased, the button's text will be updated.

The function works, however it is as if I clicked every button, not just one.

For example, I have two items to purchase. If I click "buy" on Item 1, both Item 1 and Item 2 pass through as if they were both bought. How do I make it so just Item 1 is bought?

Thank you in advance!

**views.py:**

```
def product_purchase(request):
    if request.is_ajax() and request.POST:
        user = request.user
        product_pk = request.POST.get('product_pk', False)
        product = get_object_or_404(Product, pk=product_pk)

        purchased, created = Product.objects.get_or_create(pk=product_pk)

        try:
            user_purchased = Product.objects.get(pk=product_pk, buyers=user)
        except:
            user_purchased = None

        if user_purchased:
            purchased.buyers.remove(user)
            purchased.save()
            user_has_purchased = False
        else:
            purchased.buyers.add(user)
            purchased.save()
            user_has_purchased = True

        data = {
            "user_has_purchased": user_has_purchased,
        }
        new_data = json.dumps(data)
        return HttpResponse(new_data, content_type='application/json')
    else:
        raise Http404
```

***html:***

```
{% for product in products %}
    <input class="btn btn-default selector" product="{{ product.pk }}" value="{% if request.user.username in purchased.get_buyers %} Purchased {% else %} {{ product.cost }} points {% endif %}" type="button" />
{% endfor %}
```

***javascript:***

```
$('.selector').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var $selector = $(e.currentTarget);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "{% url 'product_purchase' %}",
        data: {
            "product_pk": $(this).attr("product"),
            csrfmiddlewaretoken: "{{ csrf_token }}",
        },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            if (data.user_has_purchased) {
                $selector.val("Purchased");
            } else {
                $selector.val("{{ product.cost }} points");
                }
        },
        error: function (rs, e) {
            alert('Sorry, there was an error.');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Why do you use `get_object_or_404` and then `get_or_create`?

Comment: try `e.target` instead

Comment: @Gocht For `get_object_or_404`, the object must exist. For `get_or_create`, the purchase doesn't necessarily need to exist. That's what I am testing for in that instance.

Comment: @JAG Unfortunately, that didn't work. The same thing is still happening.

Comment: use javascript only `var selector = this;` and then `selector.value = "purchased";`

Comment: @JAG The individual button updates properly for the javascript. When the button is clicked, it changes to "Purchased" as desired. The data being passed through isn't working properly. When I refresh the page, both buttons update to "Purchased" instead of just one. Is the object supposed to be selected through a class value or another form?

Comment: what's the `product` attribute values on rendered html inputs? i suspect they are same for both inputs.

Comment: I don't quite follow what you are asking, I'm sorry. Could you please try to rephrase?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My apologies everyone. The solution was which value I passed in on my input. The correction was to change `purchased.get_buyers` to `product.get_buyers`.

Thank you all for the help though!